# How to get values from map in groovy?

Tags: groovy

Hi I have collection in my controller for ex say

```
def devices=[ [id:PPL000000011906, firstName:Adam, lastName:Baines], [id:PPL000000010836, firstName:Adam, lastName:Baines], [id:PPL000000015137, firstName:Adan, lastName:Saenz], [id:PPL000000015136, firstName:Adan, lastName:Saenz]]
```

I will be getting the id from my view. How can I get firstname and lastname values from my Map based on the ID.

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: That's not a map.  It's not even valid Groovy.  Can you edit your question to make a bit more sense?

Comment: In groovy each and every collection is treated as a map so I mentioned it as  a map though it contains list of arrays

Comment: No it isn't.  And no matter, that code still wouldn't compile. You're missing commas between the elements which you say are Arrays, but I suspect are Lists. Can you edit your question to actually put a valid example in?

Comment: Yes, can you please guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can use `find` to locate the list entry with the given `id`.  Here's an example

```
def devices = [ [id:'PPL000000011906', firstName:'Adam', lastName:'Baines'],
                [id:'PPL000000010836', firstName:'Adam', lastName:'Baines'],
                [id:'PPL000000015137', firstName:'Adan', lastName:'Saenz'],
                [id:'PPL000000015136', firstName:'Adan', lastName:'Saenz'] ]

Closure<String> nameForId = { String id ->
  devices.find { it.id == id }?.with { map ->
    "$map.firstName $map.lastName"
  }
}

assert nameForId( 'PPL000000015136' ) == 'Adan Saenz'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this to get a single field:

```
devices.find { it.id == 'PPL000000011906' }?.firstName
```

If you want closures and parameters I would do this:

```
def findPerson = { person -> devices.find { it.id == person }  }
def myPerson = findPerson('PPL000000011906')
println "FirstName: ${myPerson?.firstName} LastName: ${myPerson?.lastName}"
```

If you want to go crazy you can do this:

```
ArrayList.metaClass.findThingInMap = { field, value -> delegate.find { it[field] == value } }
```

What this does is allow you to find the value of a field  in any array list containing hash maps, which is what you have.

```
def myPerson = devices.findThingInMap('id', 'PPL000000011906')
println "FirstName: ${myPerson?.firstName} LastName: ${myPerson?.lastName}"
```

I wouldn't really do that unless you need the flexibility, but this shows the true power and awesomeness of groovy.